# Clone another element's content and order by my own classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul id="item_one">
    <li class="one">List one</li>
    <li class="three">List three</li>
    <li class="five">List five</li>
    <li class="seven">List seven</li>
</ul>
<ul id="item_two">
    <li class="two">List two</li>
    <li class="four">List four</li>
    <li class="six">List six</li>
    <li class="eight">List eight</li>
</ul>
```

I've the above HTML mark-up and I want the above mark-up into the below mark-up in a certain breakpoint using javascript / jQuery.

```
<ul id="item_one">
    <li class="one">List one</li>
    <li class="two">List two</li>
    <li class="three">List three</li>
    <li class="four">List four</li>
    <li class="five">List five</li>
    <li class="six">List six</li>
    <li class="seven">List seven</li>
    <li class="eight">List eight</li>
</ul>
```

How can I do that? Please help me..

Comment: Cloning the `li` elements between `ul` is easy. The issue will be in ordering the english language number strings as you require. I would suggest you have a master array of those values whose index you can use to sort. This won't be very robust though, as if you add a new `li.eleven` for example, you'd need to update the array. Alternatively, have another attribute you can sort by `data-order="1"`, `data-order="2"` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom data attr with number inside and then you can just use `unwrap()` and `sort()`

```js
$('#item_two li').unwrap().appendTo('#item_one');

var ul = $('#item_one').find('li').sort((a, b) => {
  return $(a).data('id') - $(b).data('id')
})

$('#item_one').empty().append(ul);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="item_one">
  <li data-id="1" class="one">List one</li>
  <li data-id="3" class="three">List three</li>
  <li data-id="5" class="five">List five</li>
  <li data-id="7" class="seven">List seven</li>
</ul>
<ul id="item_two">
  <li data-id="2" class="two">List two</li>
  <li data-id="4" class="four">List four</li>
  <li data-id="6" class="six">List six</li>
  <li data-id="8" class="eight">List eight</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. It's the exact solution, what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Hi Nenad, The solution is not working on Internet explorer and Safari Browser. There is showing "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'" problem in the safari console. How can I solve that. Could you please help me ?

Comment: @Alberuni Azad Change js code to this and try again https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/893/